# SMTP mail sending in C# (internet connection + WebProxy)

Tags: c#, smtp, webproxy

The goal is to send an email from a C# application. The code snippet below works for me, but when I run it at work (internet connection with a script configuration proxi.pac) it crashes.

Can someone help me?

```
string SendersAddress = "jd@gmail.com";
string ReceiversAddress = "dj@xxx.com";

const string SendersPassword = "xxxxxx";
const string subject = "Testing Gmail LOCAL";
const string body = "Hi This Is my Mail From Gmail";

try
{
  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
  {
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SendersAddress, SendersPassword),
    //Timeout = 3000
  };

  MailMessage message = new MailMessage(SendersAddress, ReceiversAddress, subject, body);
  smtp.Send(message);
  Console.WriteLine("Message Sent Successfully");
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: What does it crash with?

Comment: Can you get us what the exception is ? any error messages .etc. ?

Comment: Are you swallowing the exceptions? Please print them and show us the message.

Comment: From your company network you can reach Gmail? Could you check if Gmail and/or port 587 are allowed through the firewall, etc.?

Comment: Is sending does not work : smtp.Send (message)
=> InnerException {"Could not connect to remote server"}
I can not specify that a internet connection goes through a webproxi  http://mabsquid.xxxx.local/proxy.pac

Comment: Yes I can connect to gmail for my business

Comment: Ah, but do you mean you can browse to mail.gmail.com, rather than download/upload mail via an email client? If so, the proxy server may not help you and as others have said, its most likely the gmail mail ports are blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Try with port number 25.
Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>[Try Port 465](http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_SMTP_Settings.htm)</strike> Seems like port 587 is correct.

**Note** that some ISPs and proxy servers block SMTP data when it's not using port 25. This may be a deal-braker for you.

**UPDATE**
Seems like your proxy server is blocking your communication.

---

*It is interesting to note that a simple Google search cannot give a help page from Google that has the expected SMTP settings, although there are pages for POP and IMAP settings.*

Comment: It does not work with the 587, the 25 and 465
Thank you for trying

Comment: Hmm... I just tried your code running on my machine. (Nothing changed, except for my Gmail credentials. Port 587 NOT 465) and it worked. (Port 465 doesn't seems to respond, btw.) It seems like the proxy you're using is blocking your communication, rather than an issue with your code.

Comment: Also added the `catch` block which seems to be missing in your code.